# While Xero Integration to Odoo , Import data to Odoo gives an error

Tags: odoo, account, xero-api

I am integrating Xero with Odoo , so at time of importing data it is giving error like

```
XeroRateLimitExceeded: please wait before retrying the xero api
```

[image]

I also restarted the server and also changed secret api keys and consumer keys but no change

Any idea about it or any suggestion ?

Comment: i've never use xero before but i think you'll have to contact the author of the module, this doesn't seem to be an odoo specific problem

Answer (score 1):

Xero has a limit of 1000 API calls per day. I guess that creates the above issue. Make sure you read the explanation from Xero. https://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/xero-api-limits/

Comment: so In ODOO integration , when I use it's paid version instead of a 30 days trial version , shall I get this type of error or not ?

Comment: Even if it is a paid version, the error comes if the number of API calls becomes more than 1000 per day.